# Android - Async to update ui instantly when button is pressed

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get my Async to work. I will post the code in a second. Basically, I have a few squares and one of them will be randomly right. I want it so when the user pushes a button, it will check whether or not he is right or wrong, and then update the ui and then randomly produce the next button. I'm not asking for help with that, all I need is how to update the page when the button is pushed to automatically produce the next button. I am using onButton(); to produce the random button, and isUserRight(); to check whether or not the user is right or wrong. Any help would be nice, thanks in advance. Here is what I have which is not working:

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                onButton();
                ResetButtons();
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                isUserRight();
                return null;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute() {
                  onButton();
            }

        }
```

I am executing the Async class on onCreate. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem, but i can help you fix this.
It's the reason why this code is not work out is:
You don't send data to onPostExcute( method) to check whether the user is right or not.

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Boolean>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            onButton();
            ResetButtons();
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return isUserRight(); // I hope it return boolean value :3
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (result)
              onButton();
        }

    }
```

Comment: That doesn't help me very much, thanks though! Maybe my question wasn't specific enough. I need the background always checking to see if the button was pushed, if the button was pushed it will reset the buttons and start over with onButton.